# Python typing: how to name a new type?

Tags: python-3.7, python-typing

I wanted to give a name to a `dict` type, something like:

`MyDictType = Dict[int, SomeClass]`

and so I found about `NewType`, but it seems to only accepts runtime types:
the code `MyDictType = NewType('MyDictType', Dict[int, SomeClass]`
creates the warning `Expected type 'Type[_T]', got '_VT' instead`

So what is the correct way to do this?

*I'm using Python 3.7 . Please let me know if there's a better solution in newer versions.

Comment: `Foo = NewType('Foo', int)` creates a type that has basically the same values as `int`, but instances of `int` are *not* considered instances of `Foo`. That is, `isinstance(3, Foo)` is false, but `isinstance(Foo(3), Foo)` is true. `MyDictType = Dict[int, SomeClass]` makes `MyDictType` another *name* for `Dict[int, SomeClass]`. There seems to be some context missing for your definition that's needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```py
from typing import NewType

MyDictType = NewType("MyDictType", Dict[int, SomeClass])
```

NewType was added in 3.5.2, but behaviour changed in 3.10. Here're the docs for 3.10: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NewType